# robot framework capture keyword stdout logs

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a python function that I am executing inside a robot test/keyword;

```
*** Test Cases ***

Module test case: Run the engine
    @{args}=            Create List
    Append To List  ${args}  --yaml-db  ${create_sites_wf}
    Log  ${args}
    ${output}=  Run  ${args}  <<<<<<<<< entrypoint function
    Log  ${output}
```

The process doesn't return anything but it does output logs to STDOUT which robot framework captures in the test suite logs.html.  However, I need to capture these STDOUT logs within the test case and test for strings such as "SUCCESS" or "FAILURE".

Assigning the output of the keyword `Run` to a variable as above just gives me `None` (nothing is returned from `Run`).

Is there a way to capture these STDOUT logs to a test case variable and use the content in a test case?

A very contrived example of my custom keyword would be;

```
def run(args):
    if args.this:
        print("SUCCESS")
    else:
        print("FAILURE")
```

Comment: You seem to be trying to run a command named “—yaml-db”. Is that really what you are trying to do? That doesn’t look like a command. Is `Run` a custom keyword? If so, it is documented to return the output. Are you sure your command returns output?

Comment: ```Run``` is a custom keyword imported from my project that I am trying to test.  It does not return anything (returns None) but is the entry point for multiple other function calls.  All I am after is the output (STDOUT) that results from running ```Run``` with the arguments ```--yaml-db ${create_sites_wf}```.  So yes, it does run and I see the STDOUT in the log.html report but I am unable to write tests against that output.

Comment: Then the problem isn't with your test, it's with your custom keyword. Please provide a [mcve] of the custom keyword.

Comment: edited the original question with example custom keyword

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you want `run` to return something, then just add a `return` statement to `run`.

Comment: Yes, this much is obvious.  I though what i needed should be quite simple.  I just want to test on the strings that the keyword is printing to its STDOUT.  The keyword Run is really just wrapper around the entrypoint of a much larger script that will not have a single and obvious result but a series of log messages reporting the actions and results of each sub task. I was trying to avoid having to refactor or create additional code just for testing.

Comment: Is this `run` keyword using `print` statements, or some other method for sending results to stdout?

Comment: It is using python logging.